# How to use font size in VW with CkEditor4?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to use font size in **VW** in ckeditor, I have already changed from **PX** to **VW** in the *config.js* file.. but when I open the editor the font gets very small, see the image:

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because contents of any CKEditor dropdown are kept in separate `iframe` so the font size is relative to that `iframe` (viewport) size and will look very different (font will be much bigger) once you apply that font to editor content area which is kept in much bigger viewport. It can be another `iframe` (classic editor) or editable `div` (inline editor) kept on main page level and both are significantly bigger than `iframe` for dropdown.

The `vw` unit will not work in CKEditor.

Comment: Yes I figured this out, VW works on Ckeditor, but would need to fix the size of that font on the select without using her measure

Comment: What I meant by saying it won't work was that dropdown should show the actual font size which will be used in editor content area (this is what wysiwyg is about). Since `vw` is relative to viewport there is no way workaround or fix this problem in the editor.